# Update multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 tables namely Profile and Info.

My table looked like this:

PROFILE

```
| p_Id | FirstName | LastName |

| 1    | Jack      | Cole     | 
| 2    | Cynthia   | Cole     | 
| 3    | Robert    | Cole     |
```

INFO

```
| I_Id | childsID | fathersID | mothersID | Country |

| 1    | 1        | 3         | 2         | USA     |
```

I'm retrieving values from those tables by displaying them in textboxes, my select query is:

```
SELECT p.p_Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName, i.*, 
(SELECT pp.FirstName+' '+pp.LastName FROM Profile pp WHERE pp.p_Id=i.childsID) AS child,
(SELECT pp.FirstName+' '+pp.LastName FROM Profile pp WHERE pp.p_Id=i.fathersID) AS father,
(SELECT pp.FirstName+' '+pp.LastName FROM Profile pp WHERE pp.p_Id=i.mothersID) AS mother
    FROM Info i
        INNER JOIN Profile p
            ON p.p_Id=i.childsID
```

no problem with select, I'm able to display values on textboxes, but the problem is, I can't update them, I have tried so far this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Profile SET FirstName=@fname, LastName=@lname WHERE p_Id = @pid;
                            UPDATE Info SET childsID=@child, fathersID=@father, mothersID=@mother, Country=@country WHERE I_Id = @iid;";

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fname", txtfname.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lname", txtlname.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@child", txtchild.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@father", txtfather.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mother", txtmother.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@country", txtcountry.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid", txtpid.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iid", txtiid.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
    }
```

I'm using c# and Asp.net
Thanks in advance :) God Bless

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to pass a batch of SQL update statements into the `CommandText` of a single `SqlCommand` object and the add parameters which will be used by all the updates in the batch.

Comment: This question is being posted repeatedly, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586456/update-query-with-multiple-tables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588835/select-to-update

Answer (score 0):

Check the MSDN: [SqlParameter Constructor (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y.aspx)

> When you specify an Object in the value parameter, the SqlDbType is inferred from the Microsoft .NET Framework type of the Object.

So when you passing int type parameters you need to convert text value to integer:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid", int.Parse(txtpid.Text)));
```

or better:

```
int tempIntValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pid", int.TryParse(txtpid.Text, out tempIntValue)?
  (object)intTempValue: (object)DbNull.Value ));
```